# Unable to create box shadow on li pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a box shaadow on a image but somehow I am unable to create one. I am using the `:after` pseudo element to do it:

HTML ::

```
<ul class="bxslider fade out">
    <li>
        <img src="http://unilaboralgirona.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ZContact.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS ::

```
  .bxslider {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  .bxslider li {
      position: relative;
  }
  .bxslider li:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 30px;
      ;
      position: absolute;
      top:100%;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
  .bxslider li img {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 300px;
  }
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cxy39rLg/)**

Now ofcource since `img` does't support pseudo elements I am adding the shadow to the `li` element, but still I see no shadow and I don't understand why ?

Can somebody explain? Also in the console in FF, no pseudo  elements are shown.

P.S. The reason I am using pseudo elements is because the box-shadow has to be less than 100% of the `li`'s width , but for now, doesn't take this into account.

Comment: You are missing `content: "";`

Comment: @Muhammet i can't beleive that happened ! .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/103scs2v/

Comment: `content` was the problem indeed !

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding your CSS for the shadow using the following selector `.bxslider li img:hover`.

http://jsfiddle.net/cxy39rLg/1/

```
 .bxslider li img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
.bxslider li img:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the try , but have to use a psedo element !